# Decoding Stack Trace error

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am looking at the crash history and the following appears.  Is there a way to identify what is the error or how to resolve?  Is there any place where it identifies the error codes?

Exception Type: system.exception

> Frame    Image               Function                Offset
>   0        windows_ni  Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizer..ctor 0x00000001
>   1        carparkcommon_ni   GetMeALot.Helpers.Speech.Initialize 0x00000040
>   2        getmealot_ni       GetMeALot.MainPage+_PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_d__b.MoveNext  0x0000007e
>   3        mscorlib_ni System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore._ThrowAsync_b__0 0x00000036

Exception Type: system.argumentoutofrangeexception

> Frame    Image               Function                               Offset
>   0        system_core_ni     System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]] 0x00000122
>   1        carparkcommon_ni   GetMeALot.Helpers.Speech.Initialize    0x00000128
>   2        getmealot_ni       GetMeALot.MainPage+_PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_d__b.MoveNext 0x0000007e
>   3        mscorlib_ni        Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore._ThrowAsync_b__0 0x00000036

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be related to your creation of a new `SpeechRecognizer` in the `Loaded` event of the `MainPage`.